# Creating a hamburger menu with shortening lines

Tags: html, css

Need to make a hamburger item with each line shorter than the last.

E.g.

```
------
 -----
  ----
```

My idea is just to have a div with 3 spans inside it.

```
<label for="menu_collapse_icon" class="menu_collapse_icon_label">
    <span class="menu_bar"></span>
    <span class="menu_bar"></span>
    <span class="menu_bar"></span>
</label>
```

And then in the CSS do e.g:

```
.menu_collapse_icon {
    FOR EACH SPAN, REDUCE ITS LENGTH BY X AMOUNT?
}
```

But I don't know how to do this? I could just create 3 separate length bars, but would rather do it this way.

Comment: Not possible with a single selector. You would have to select/address each span separately. Also a span's properties can't be determined by reference to a previous sibling's properties.

Answer (score 0):

Add each element inside each other to create cascade:

```css
.menu_bar {
  padding-top: 10px;
  width: 80%;
  display: inline-block;
  border-top: 1px solid #454545;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.menu_collapse_icon_label {
  width: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 0;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 10px 10px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<label for="menu_collapse_icon" class="menu_collapse_icon_label">
  <div class="menu_bar">
    <div class="menu_bar">
      <div class="menu_bar"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

With the markup that you plan to have, this is not possible with a single selector. And am sure you will find many examples if you search.

However, am presenting this just for the sake of getting it done with a single selector. You will need nested elements for this.

```css
label {
    display: block; text-align: right;
    border: 1px solid #bbb; 
    width: 32px; height: 32px;
    padding: 4px 8px 4px 0px;
}
label span {
    display: block; float: right; position: relative;
    width: 75%; right: 0px; top: 8px; 
    border-bottom: 2px solid #999;
}
label > span { margin-top: -4px; }
```

```html
<label for="menu_collapse_icon" class="menu_collapse_icon_label">
    <span class="menu_bar">
        <span class="menu_bar">
            <span class="menu_bar"></span>
        </span>    
    </span>   
</label>
```

Comment: And this is obviously from a semantic HTML perspective a bad idea. (And won't work when using `a` as container.)

Comment: @BramVanroy: I agree on the semantics, that is why included the statement *"just for the sake of"*. BTW: it will very well work with an `a` as container -- http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/d9u0qenL/1/

Comment: I meant `a` instead of `span`, which won't work due to the event bubbling. But I now realise that I misunderstood the question. I thought he wanted to use the spans as list items. Apparently it's just meant as decoration. In that case I'd just create an SVG icon...

Answer (score 0):

I *suppose* you could do something like below. You could probably make it responsive if you use percentages for `i` and the pseudo elements.

```css
label {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc; 
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    position: relative;
}

i {
    display: block;
    background: #999;
    height: 2px;
    width: 50%;
    
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -1px;
    right: 4px;
}
i::before, i::after {
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    height: 2px;
    background: #999;
    content: "";
}
i::before {
    width: 120%;
    top: -8px;
}
i::after {
    width: 80%;
    bottom: -8px;
}
```

```html
<label for="menu_collapse_icon" class="menu_collapse_icon_label">
    <i class="menu-icon"></i>
</label>
```

However, I discourage it. You'd be better of creating an (SVG) icon that looks like this, and use it inline.

---

I managed to make it responsive, as a quick bit of fun. However, I do encourage you to look into icons. Here's the link to [the responsive show case](http://jsfiddle.net/zqj9sbpd/2/).

Important CSS:

```
i {
    display: block;
    background: #999;
    height: 4%;
    width: 50%;

    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    right: 12%;
}
i::before, i::after {
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    background: #999;
    content: "";
}
i::before {
    width: 125%;
    top: -400%;
}
i::after {
    width: 75%;
    bottom: -400%;
}
```